# facebook Graph API "/pageid/feed" returns blank

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed, facebook-authentication

1) I got my facebook app setup.
2) I got my facebook page id, app_secret and access token.

```
function fetchUrl($url) {

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

  $feedData = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch); 

  return $feedData;

}

$profile_id = "288644066152";

//App Info, needed for Auth
$app_id = "appid";
$app_secret = "app_secret";  // do not expose app secret!

//Retrieve auth token
$authToken = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id={$app_id}&client_secret={$app_secret}");

$json_object = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/{$profile_id}/feed?{$authToken}");

print_r($json_object);
```

RETURNS:

```
{"data":[]}
```

Any help out there?
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if you want to show your secrete api key

Comment: there is a bug reported for this.  User auth is failing in php-sdk and beyond https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/358274774239901?browse=search_4fe9dfdf191df5c02578289

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of access tokens. The user access token, & the app access token.

Try something like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=******&redirect_uri=*************&scope=user_about_me,publish_stream,friends_about_me,****&state=SOMETHING
```

Comment: I've suggested an edit to your post. Please try to use proper English and formatting as much as you can. :)